# C2665 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, clr

I'm very new to C++ and was looking for help regarding this. I am using the IDE Visual Studio Community and I am fairly new to both the language and this code editor.
Below is the functional, and nonfunctional, code. I also am working on a CLR Console App (.NET Framework) if that helps

```cpp
private: System::Void GenerateQuote(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        string QuoteEntered = "hi";
        std::cout << "Enter your quote!";
        //std::cin >> QuoteEntered;
        QuoteBox->Text = QuoteEntered;
        //std::cin >> "hi";
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work, as I am using a variable to represent the string, but below seems to work just fine.

```cpp
private: System::Void GenerateQuote(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        //string QuoteEntered = "hi";
        std::cout << "Enter your quote!";
        //std::cin >> QuoteEntered;
        QuoteBox->Text = "hi";
        //std::cin >> "hi";
    }
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to make it so I can use the console to input a string that can be used as QuoteEntered, and then I set QuoteBox.Text to QuoteEntered.

Answer (score -1):

C++/CLI does not have nice integration with the standard I/O streams such as cin and cout.

I think you will have more success using the .NET methods to read from the Console class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0

Try something like this:

```
private: System::Void GenerateQuote(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    System::Console::WriteLine("Enter your quote!");
    String^ entered = System::Console::ReadLine();
    if (entered != nullptr)
       QuoteBox->Text = entered;
}
```